# Could Gollum still reproduce?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, sexuality

It has been [pointed out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3871096#3871096) that Gollum wouldn't win a beauty-contest. But after all these years of being poisoned by The Ring, would he still be physically able to reproduce? And if so, would his offspring be as consumed by The Ring as he is, or would they be "normal"?

Comment: @Izkata: I completely forgot the link. There it is :)

Comment: -1 for judging human beings by beauty contests!

Comment: @DVK: Gollum's not a human being. Also, you got me wrong: In chat it was discussed in which conditions his "bits" would be after that time. I was not referring to Gollum's physical appearance. *You* inferred that all yourself!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no indication that the Ring has any negative impact upon a being's physical abilities.  Gollum is still going strong, traipsing through Mirkwood, Mordor, the Dead Marshes, etc., despite being almost 600 years old.  The Ring's long term impact has two main effects, leaving the bearer "tired" and "weary" (as mentioned in both the Hobbit, in regards to Gollum, and the Lord of the Rings, in regards to Bilbo), and shifting its bearer into the Unseen world.  Neither of these would have any impact upon a bearer's ability to have children, other than the usual age-related problems.

With regards to passing Ring-consumption through to children, it is hard to see why that would be possible.  The Ring specifically affects its bearer.  It has no effect upon others around it (other than greed for it, if they know of its existence and power).  Following on from the previous paragraph's extrapolation, if the bearer of the Ring has children, there is no indication that there is any impact upon their children.

The only instance we have of a bearer having children (albeit one who was a bearer only for a limited period of time) is Sam, and he is listed as having thirteen children.  It can be argued that, despite his brief encounter with the Ring personally, it did have an effect on him as he was also quite long-lived and healthy for a Hobbit in his later years before his departure to the Grey Havens and beyond.  However, it obviously had no impact upon his ability to have children, nor on his children themselves.

Comment: Interesting. This raises the question if children that were conceived while one of their parents was bearing the Ring would be affected.

Comment: I misread that as raising a different question... what about children that were conceived while one of their parents was _wearing_ the Ring? :P

Comment: The way it transformed Smeagol to Gollum, being all stretched and slimey etc. I'd be very surprised if Gollum didn't have impotence issues, let alone being able to actually seed the deal so to speak.

Comment: @dlanod: What's the difference between those words (perhaps I should ask that on ELU.SE)?

Comment: @bitmask: In LotR, a Ring bearer is one who carries (bears) it and has worn it.  There is only one bearer of the Ring at a time.  Wearing the Ring is specifically when you're invisible.

Comment: @dlanod: Well, then I was referring to *wearing* it proper.

Comment: Hmmm... I think we just went into a realm that only fanfiction has ever gone before... Procreation while wearing a ring of invisibility. Hokay then.